# cURL inventory update to Shopify API not working

Tags: php, json, api, curl, shopify

Please review my cURL test code and let me know if you see any reason why executing it does not update the inventory of my product Variant. There is only one Product that has it's Variant data, there are not separate Variants of the Product. So it should be pretty straight-forward, right?

cURL is installed and is working fine on my box, and the API key / token are also verified.

Here is my code

---

```
//Set up access

$apiKey = "[my api key]";
$pwd = "[my pwd]";

$baseUrl = $apiKey . $pwd ."@sensible-herbs.myshopify.com/admin/";

//Set up test data  

  $variantId = '3744859331';
  $inventoryQty = '50';

//Set up JSON payload

$payload = array (            
   "variant" => array("id" => $variantId,
   " nventory_quantity" => $inventoryQty
   )               
);  

$payload = json_encode($payload, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo 'JSON payload: ' .$payload  ."<p>";

$putUrl = $baseUrl ."variants/" ."$variantId".".json";
echo 'url: ' .$putUrl ."<hr>";

$session = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $putUrl);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30); //seconds to allow for connection
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //seconds to allow for cURL commands
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); //include header info in return value ? 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //return response as a string
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_PUT, 1); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json'));

$data = curl_exec($session);

print_r(curl_getinfo($session));

curl_close($session);

echo $data; // session data
```

---

The response I am getting is:

Array ( [url] => https://[apikey+password]@sensible-herbs.myshopify.com/admin/variants/3744859331.json [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.156 [namelookup_time] => 0.078 [connect_time] => 0.156 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => 23.227.38.71 [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 192.168.0.10 [local_port] => 50573 [redirect_url] => )

So it looks like it's connecting but either the payload is not getting PUT...or I just don't understand what the API / URL requirements are for this... or maybe there is some hidden or missing switch or permission I need to set up other than the APIKey generation... I wish I knew!

Thanks in advance and namaste!

Kailas

Comment: What is returned with `echo curl_error($session);` ?

Comment: Thank you for your debugging suggestion. I was not sure of the best way to retrieve useful information. It said: 

SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: I added:
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
and the SSL error was eliminated

Comment: I can do a GET and get my Product Variant data. But a PUT does not change my Product Variant inventory quantity.

Comment: I am also getting:
{"errors":{"variant":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

Comment: You should check this - [https://docs.shopify.com/api/product#update]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a spell mistake in your payload array, `inventory_quantity` not  `nventory_quantity`

```
$payload = array (            
   "variant" => array(
       "id" => $variantId,
       "inventory_quantity" => $inventoryQty
   )               
);
```

Comment: For anyone finding this in 2024: You can't use the `/variants/*.json` endpoint to update `inventory_quantity` any more. You have to use the [Inventory Level API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2024-01/resources/inventorylevel#post-inventory-levels-adjust), and to do that you need each variant's inventory ID, as you need to send its inventory _location_. It is... a lot. Good luck with those rate limits 